# why do I get a strange answer?

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor, floating-point

So I'm working on basic class constructors. The problem is, the answer I get when I use the dot operator to find the speed of my Horse object makes little sense and I would like to know whats going wrong and how to correct it?

```
class Horse{
      public:
      string sName;
      double dDist;
      double dTime;

      //constructor
      Horse(string sHorseName, double dDistance, double dSecs){
      sName = sHorseName;
      dDist = dDistance;
      dSecs = dTime;
      }

      double dSpeed(){
             return (dDist/dTime);
      }


      };



     int main(){
        Horse Horse1("frankel", 11.40, 122);
        cout << Horse1.dSpeed() << " m/s. " << endl;
        cout << Horse1.sName << endl;
        return 0;
        }
```

The answer the program gives is 5.95461e+306 which is clearly wrong. Why am I getting this answer?

Answer (score 4):

You run into undefined behavior on `dSecs = dTime;` because `dTime` was never initialized. After that, all bets are off.

You probably ment `dTime = dSecs`.

Comment: thanks, completely overlooked that it should be dTime = dSecs

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you have an error in your constructor. If you had implemented it using the constructor initialization list, which is the recommended method, then you would have produced a compiler error.

```
Horse(string sHorseName, double dDistance, double dSecs) : sName(sHorseName), sDist(sDistance), dTime(dSecs) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning `dTime` to `dSecs` when it needs to be the other way around, and your constructor takes your `dDistance` and `dSecs` parameters in a different order than what you're passing to it (assuming the horse travelled 122 meters in 11.40 seconds, not 11.40 meters in 122 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, invert the following line:

```
dSecs = dTime;
```